# Does magrib last until redness disappear (nearly 15 minutes) or until isha (nearly a hour)?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

I've always heard that the time for maghrib is about 15 minutes after it start i.e the time for the red afterglow to disappear. But now i'm hearing that maghrib doesn't end until Isha' starts which is about 1 hour after maghrib starts. so how long does maghrib actually last? Is it permissible to delay maghrib for about an hour due to work if there is no other option?

Comment: i want to know the exact same thing but there are so many different answers

Answer (score 4):

The following [hadith](http://sunnah.com/muslim/5/222) of Sahih Muslim says:

> وَوَقْتُ صَلاَةِ الْمَغْرِبِ مَا لَمْ يَغِبِ **الشَّفَقُ**
>
> the time of the Maghrib prayer is as long as the **Shafaq** has not
>   disappeared

The Shafaq may refer to:

1. the red light that appears when the sun is below the horizon
2. the white light that appears after the red light

I believe this has caused the difference of opinion that you have mentioned. If this word is used in both meanings in the Arabic language then I see no reason why it must be restricted to the first one while determining the time of Maghrib prayer.

Answer (score 1):

according to hadith http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/4 ,

> Then he *(the Prophet)* ordered him to call the Iqamah for Isha when the
>   horizon (twilight) had vanished.

... on the next day :

> Then he ordered him to delay Maghrib until right before the twilight
>   had disappeared.

and same word "shafaq" is used in this cases, so last time of maghrib is only little time before start time of isha.

but whether "shafaq" means red light or even white light after it - i am not sure, different alims and mazhabs choosed different opinion, as i know. i tend to think it is white light, because it should disappear, according to this hadith, and there are many hadithes like this, and red light does not completely disappear because white light is left after it, and it is simmetrical and similar to the end of night and start of fajr time.

Comment: So for my clarification please answer, does it mean that both times i.e. 15 minutes and about 1 hour are valid?

Comment: i think 15 minutes is wrong , it is too short. maybe it is 1 hour or 1.5 hours . it is red light. including white light it maybe 2 hours and more.

Answer (score 0):

time of Maghrib is from full sunset to Isha.
time of Isha is from the full disappearance of the redness of twilight.
when the sun is below the horizon 12-13 degrees there will be no twilight redness in the sky.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. Also consider elaborating and adding evidences to support your claims and read [answer].

Answer (score -2):

Very detail explanation and the different opinions and the majorities opinions about this on this website:
https://www.wrightstreetmosque.com/ascertaining-the-time-at-which-the-ishaa-prayer-begins-and-ends-and-the-issue-of-praying-it-after-midnight/#_ftn10

Comment: Please include the relevant content in your answer rather than just linking to it. Your link will be useless after a couple of years when it expires.